# Defining density of a random function using Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$ be a probability space and $E$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and $\mathbb{B}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subset of $E$.

Let $X$ be random function defined on $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$ taking values in $(E,\mathbb{B})$. Example of such random function $X$ is stochastic processes with square integrable sample paths on the real line when $E= L_2(R)$.

Let $P_X$ be the induced probability measure induced by by $X$ on $(E,\mathbb{B})$.

I want to define the density of $X$ using Radon-Nikodym Theorem. So I need a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ (say) which dominates the $\sigma$-finite measure $P_X$.

I am stuck here. How to find $\mu$ in this case?

Any suggestion, solution or useful reference will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: @ janak : I think that what you want to say is that $P_X$ is the push forward measure of $P$ by $X$. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: Yes, $P_X$ is push forward measure.

Comment: To stimulate this thread you should try to say more precisely what you are looking for. As stated, your question does not make much sense (you could take $\mu=P_X$ and density $1$). For $E=C([0,\infty))$ the Wiener measure (distribution of Brownian motion) is certainly an interesting measure on $E$, but without more context it is not clear whether this is an interesting case for you.

Comment: The context of my question is: I have a set of parametric curves $\beta(t)=(x(t),y(t))', t\in [0,1]$ (for example $x(t)=sin t$ and $y(t)=cos t$). I consider these curves are random sample from population of parametric curves and I try to understand whether I can define probability density function of this random curves.

Comment: I understand the space of such parametric curves is no longer a linear space. But I think it  could be a valid question to ask whether the density of the random curve are exists or not.

Comment: Density is just one representation of a probability measure (through another measure) and it is useful as a tool, when it comes up naturally, not as a goal: by itself it does not tell anything new about probabilities. Now, in the space you've described a natural measure would be the Wiener measure as @Jochen mentioned, but if I'm not mistaken your $P_X$ is singular w.r.t. the Wiener measure. The question is what were you going to do *after* you'd get a density - if you specify that, I guess the conclusion would be that you don't really need density.